# Golangci unparam linter not working in VS code

Tags: go, golangci-lint

I have enabled unparam linter in my config but its not detecting any warnings for my code

This shows for unparam when I run golangci-lint linters:

> Enabled by your configuration linters: unparam: Reports unused
> function parameters [fast: false, auto-fix: false]

Here's my config:

```
run:
  modules-download-mode: readonly

linters-settings:
  unparam:
    check-exported: true    # Check for exported functions

linters:
  disable-all: true
  enable:
    - unparam
```

My main.go file:

```
/ Example function with an unused parameter
func ExampleFunc(x int, y string) {
    fmt.Println(y)  // Using y, so it's not reported as unused
}

func main() {
    // Calling the function with only one argument
    myString:="Hello" 
    myInt:=42

    ExampleFunc(myInt,myString)
}
```

When i run golangci-lint run,it doesn't show any errors.My golangci version is 1.56.2 and os is Mac.

Comment: The particular linter rule has some exceptions to avoid false positives, take a look at https://github.com/mvdan/unparam

Comment: Can you try with an older version of golanci and see if the same config works on the same code?

Comment: I tried with v1.54.2 and v1.53.2 but still doesn't work